# Xamarin Forms Android - Scoped Storage Access (Android API 30)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, storage

Currently I'm in the process of updating my application to work with Android API 30 to comply with Googles new Privacy Rules. Prior to this I was using the "Use legacy storage" flag so I could access Public storage with ease once Read/Write permissions were achieved, however that's no longer available in the latest API.

For a temporary workaround I am using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE or Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree (In Xamarin) in order to gain read / write access to the device bluetooth folder (It has to be this folder as that's where im looking for the specific files).

Whilst this method works, it's not ideal for a regular user as it requires them to actually search and find the folder instead of just getting a pop up asking for access.

[What the process currently looks like #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZRkU.png)

[What the process currently looks like #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWtv5.png)

[What the process currently looks like #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yXxC.png)

Ideally what I'm after is Image 3 to be the only interaction the user has to perform in order to give access to this particular folder. However Xamarin Documentation isn't particuarly clear (Especially on these new storage API's) and was hoping someone could help point me in the right direction!

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks :)

Comment: `Prior to this I was using the "Use legacy storage" flag so I could access Public storage with ease once Read/Write permissions were achieved, however that's no longer available in the latest API.` Please use the right name for that flag. Keep it in your manifest as it is needed vor your app tobrun on Android Q/10 devices.

Comment: `device bluetooth folder` I have never heard of such a folder. Please tell full path.

Comment: By "Use Legacy Storage" I was referring to this flag: android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" which is still in place and working for < API 29, however this flag is ignored in API 30.

Comment: @blackapps

Clarification for legacy storage above and the Device Bluetooth Folder im referring to is the folder automatically created by Android upon recieving a bluetooth file and can be located at: /storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/

Comment: Has the bluetooth folder creation anything to do with your app? Did your app create that folder?

Comment: @blackapps No, the folder is automatically created by Android upon recieving a bluetooth file (which is in this case a .txt document). 

As stated in the question, the issue isn't with finding the folder as I know where it is and can access it with Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree, I just would like to know if there is a way to shorten the current process down to just the third image, instead of the user being required to find the folder themselves to allow access as it's not very user friendly.

Comment: It seems that you want to let the gui for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE open in the 'bluetooth' directory? Then why not say so? Has nothing to do with Scoped Storage access mentioned in the subject of your post..

Comment: This absolutely has everything to do with Scoped Storage Access. Its about retrieving Scoped Storage access (to the bluetooth folder, which is outside of the apps data folder) only using the prompt shown in the third image ideally, without needing the rest of the file picking process as shown in image 1 and 2. It's also further relevant to the topic as a whole, as Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree may be not be ideal for my use case of getting Scoped File Access to the Bluetooth folder, if so what would be? Even if the subject is not 100% clear, i've made by description very clear.

Comment: `Scoped File Access to the Bluetooth folder,` Whatever you mean by that. I can only conclude that, as said before, you want to let ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE open in the 'bluetooth' directory. And you dont know how to do that.

Comment: When I refer to Scoped Storage I mean that with the recent API changes you now have to request read / write access to a specific folder outside of pre-approved directories e.g. Bluetooth (thus declaring your scope) using the S.A.F or the MediaStore API to do so.

Comment: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE works but is too complicated for the end user as it requires 3 steps: 1. Find the folder,  2. Select the folder and 3. Approve the read / write permissions to the selected folder. I need it so only step 3 is presented to the user, as shown in image 3. Essentially asking if part of ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE can be automated.

Comment: I do not see that essence in the title of your post.

Comment: As I said earlier "Even if the subject is not 100% clear, i've made my description very clear.". You now have adaquate understanding of the issue at hand, despite me just repeating information in the existing description (which you must not have read in the first place). Instead you have just been pedantic about the title of the post. Do you have an answer to the question in the description, yes or no? Please tell me how you would summarise a short relevant title, so this does not happen in the future.

Comment: As said before: `you want to let ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE open in the 'bluetooth' directory`

Comment: Yes, without forcing the user to 1. find the folder and 2. click select folder - I only want it to pop up and say "Allow appname Access to X folder?" as shown in the third image I have supplied.

Comment: This is a normal procedure for requesting a view of the file, which is also intended to keep the data safe.  When we could have direct access to a file data, it is very risky.